# Can I use LINQPad on MS Access data directly, or by passing args to a Web API Rest method?

Tags: c#, rest, ms-access, asp.net-web-api, linqpad

I want to test out the LINQ in my Repository code:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, string packSize, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.Id, ID)).Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.PackSize.ToString(), packSize)).Take(CountToFetch);
}
```

...and am trying to use LINQPad to do that.

The data comes from an MS Access database; seeing that LINQPad doesn't seem to support Access "out of the box" that way, I wonder if either there's a driver for that (couldn't fine one - don't have the DevExpress product needed to use their driver), or if I could query by attaching to my Web API Rest method inside LINQPad?

I tried the SQL Server driver, hoping that would work for Access, too; I tried the WCF driver, hoping maybe that would work with Web API, but neither worked; with the latter attempt, I got, "XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a 'Microsoft Access Data Context Driver' for LinqPad

You can download it here: [MSAccessDataContextDriver.lpx](http://dnm-ict.nl/downloads/msaccessdatacontextdriver.ashx)

View a screenshot here: [LinqPad Northwind.accdb](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7s1LC3MXM6g/UpXSviM_B1I/AAAAAAAAAEU/8VtyAxeIWYc/s1600/MSAccessDataContextDriver-RES.png)

**UPDATE** (5 Nov 2014) The driver now supports password protected MS Access databases

Comment: I downloaded that; it's an "lpx" file; I don't know what that is; my machine didn't want to open it, also didn't know what it is.

Comment: Clay, download the .lpx-file, in LinqPad, click on Add connection, then click on 'view more drivers...' then click on 'browse' and select the .lpx-file the driver is added on the top list-box

Comment: **Note:** For anyone trying to use the .lpx file: Please make sure you're **not** using the 64bit (AnyCPU) version of LinqPad. Otherwise you'll get the strange error message  "Error: InvalidOperationException - The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." The 32bit Version of LinqPad works fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this LinqPad blog about how one person managed to connect and query MS Access.

[how-to-connect-to-and-query-a-ms-access-database-mdb-and-accdb](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/384/how-to-connect-to-and-query-a-ms-access-database-mdb-and-accdb)

One other possible solution is to use XPO persistent classes to connect to MS Access.

[This topic describes how to install the driver and use it to query XPO persistent classes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument10739)

[LinqPad Data Context Drivers](http://www.linqpad.net/richclient/datacontextdrivers.aspx)

There also might be a way to use the [IQ Drivers](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/65/iq-driver-for-ms-access). I am not sure if connections to MS Access have been added.

Hope this helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given above, you can also do the following (which works not only for Access, but also for MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and a couple of other database systems):

1. Click "Add connection" in LinqPad
2. The "Choose Data Context" dialog opens
3. Click the button <kbd>View more drivers...</kbd>
4. Scroll down a bit until you see "LINQ to DB Driver"
5. Click on the link button **"Download & Enable Driver"**.
6. Wait until you see "Driver successfully updated." Then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. You should see the "Choose Data Context" dialog again, but this time with an additional entry **"LINQ to DB"**. Select it and Click <kbd>Next ></kbd>
8. The "LINQ to DB Connection" dialog opens. As Data Provider select "Microsoft Access"
9. Enter a **connection string<sup>*)</sup>** like for example `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\myAccessDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False`
10. Verify the connection by clicking <kbd>Test</kbd>. It should give you a "Successful!" message.
11. Close the dialog by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>

Now you're ready using your Access database.

---

<sub>**<sup>*)</sup>Hint:** To create a **valid connection string,** you can use the following trick: 
Create a new, empty text file on the desktop and give it the extension `.udl`, for example `Connection.udl`. Then, double click on it and you will get a configuration dialog where you can select a provider, enter server, database etc. as required. Confirm it with <kbd>OK</kbd> and open the file `Connection.udl` with Notepad afterwards. You will see a valid connection string that you can copy and paste (copy just the line `Provider=...`).</sub>